# Set variable inside heredoc, use variable outside heredoc

Tags: bash, shell, variable, here-document

I've got the following in a bash script

```
ssh -T -i ${ssh_key} ${ssh_user}@${host} <<- 'EOF'
  file=`hostname`.tar.gz
  echo "file: " $file 
  ### prints>> file: some-host-name.tar.gz 
EOF

scp -i ${ssh_key} ${ssh_user}@${host}:${file} ~/incoming
### prints>> scp -i /home/user/.ssh/key.pem user@192.168.1.1: ~/incoming
```

I'm trying to set the filename inside the heredoc, as it's based on the host I'm connecting to. I then want to use that filename to scp the file to another location, but I can't get the filename outside of the heredoc.

Suggestions?

Comment: You have quoted `'EOF'`, no expansion was performed in body of here-document. Anyway, variable assignment was not performed inside here-document.

Comment: file variable is being assigned in sub shell created for SSH session. Parent shell is unable to access those variables.. You can go with solution mentioned by @muru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of heredocs. If you'd run:

```
ssh -i ${ssh_key} ${ssh_user}@${host} sh -c '
  file=`hostname`.tar.gz
  echo "file: " $file
'
```

The effect would have been the same. Point being: variable is evaluated in the shell started by SSH on the remote server. There's nothing it can do to affect a variable on the local shell.

So, instead, do:

```
file=$(ssh -i ${ssh_key} ${ssh_user}@${host} hostname).tar.gz
scp -i ${ssh_key} ${ssh_user}@${host}:${file} ~/incoming
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for providing the alternative, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
remote_user_name=user
instance_ip=127.0.0.1
external=$(ls /home/)

ssh -T -i ${private_key}  -l ${remote_user_name} ${instance_ip} << END
  internal=\$(ls /home/)
  echo "\${internal}"
  echo "${external}"
END
```